# Posting an image to Instagram through Instasharp API

Tags: c#, asp.net, instagram, instasharp

With the new API changes, is it possible to post images to Instagram with Instasharp or any other API?

I looked at Instagram API, I only see GET, I can see that we can't post to Instagram yet. Am I right? https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

The posts here regarding this topic are a few years old.. So, if anyone who worked on this in the recent times please share your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Its not possible to post images via API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, you can't post an image on Instagram through their APIs.